# Why is TcpListener.incoming() infinite?

Tags: rust, tcp

I'm learning Rust and going through the Rust book, chapter 20 and interested in the piece of code in [Listing 20-1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-01-single-threaded.html), also down below:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        println!("Connection established!");
    }
}
```

The book explains:

> Overall, this for loop will process each connection in turn and produce a series of streams for us to handle. [...] The reason we might receive errors from the incoming method when a client connects to the server is that we’re not actually iterating over connections. Instead, we’re iterating over connection attempts.

My question is why does does the for loop `for stream in listener.incoming()` run infinitely? I thought that `listener.incoming()` is called only once and the for loop will iterate until it hits a None value and then stop.
How come it does not just run once through the iterator?

Comment: *"the for loop will iterate until it hits a None value"* -- you just answered your own question. If the iterator returned from `incoming()` never returns `None`, the loop will never stop. Per [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.incoming): *"The returned iterator will never return None"*

Comment: A bit of nuance: `listener.incoming()` _does_ run once, and it returns an iterator object that the `for` loop uses.